# User is not authenticated identity server 4

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Problem

I have a three projects.

1. A web application
2. An API
3. An identity server

The problem i am having is when i add the authorize attribute to the api controllers i am not able to hit the API.

Here is my config file from identity server

```
public class Config
{
    public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "Stephen",
                Password = "Password",
                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
             new IdentityResources.Email(),
            new IdentityResource
            {
                Name = "role",
                UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"}
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetAllApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
           new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "crmApi",
                DisplayName = "API #1",
                Description = "Allow the application to access API #1 on your behalf",
                Scopes = new List<string> {"crmApi"},
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("secret".Sha256())}, // change me!
                UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"}
                
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ApiScope("crmApi", "Access to API #1"),
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "crmApi" }
            },

              new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientName = "MVC Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
          RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44315/signin-oidc"},
          PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44315/signout-callback-oidc"},

           AllowedScopes =new List<string>
           {
               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
              "role",
              "crmApi"
           }
        },
    };


    }
}
```

Here is the identity server startup file

```
   public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        var connectionString = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:Database").Value;
        var migrationAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(builder =>
         builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>();

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        InitialISDatabase(app);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax });
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }

    private void InitialISDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();

            if (!context.Clients.Any())
            {
                foreach (var client in Config.GetClients())
                {
                    context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }


            if (!context.IdentityResources.Any())
            {
                foreach (var resource in Config.GetIdentityResources())
                {
                    context.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.ApiScopes.Any())
            {
                foreach (var scope in Config.GetApiScopes())
                {
                    context.ApiScopes.Add(scope.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.ApiResources.Any())
            {
                foreach (var api in Config.GetAllApiResources())
                {
                    context.ApiResources.Add(api.ToEntity());
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            if (!userManager.Users.Any())
            {
                foreach (var testUser in Config.GetUsers())
                {
                    var identityUser = new IdentityUser(testUser.Username)
                    {
                        Id = testUser.SubjectId
                    };

                    userManager.CreateAsync(identityUser, "Password123!").Wait();
                    userManager.AddClaimsAsync(identityUser, testUser.Claims.ToList()).Wait();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the api startup file.

```
   public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44302/";
                options.ApiName = "crmApi";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
               
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddControllers();

      
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the web project startup file.

```
   public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44302/";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
           
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your api startup.

Comment: i did. it says here is my api startup

Comment: Try adding  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes="Bearer")] to the controller.

Comment: i removed   .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers()) and added the attirbute to the controller. identity server says user is not authenicated, but exists in db

Comment: See here, add authentication to startup like here, https://github.com/LalitaCode/IdentityServerSubdomainMultiTenant/blob/master/API/Startup.cs

Comment: but i want to just identity server. not just jwt

Comment: Try adding [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes=IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]. I am from mobile so can’t answer properly, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ApiScopes` and `ApiResources` to IdentityServer setup, either in DB or in memory

To add them in memory you need to change your code to be like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetApiScopes())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetAllApiResources())`
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>(); ;
```

And if you are adding them in DB you need to make sure, you have tables as `ApiResourceScopes` and `ApiScopeProperties`

Read more about IDS4 DB [here](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/migrating-your-identityserver4-v3-database-to-identityserver4-v4)

The other option is to change the API to remove audience validation. API authorization will work, as long as access_token is issued by your IdentityServer. To do this change the code on on API to be like:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer("Bearer",
   options =>
   {
      options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
      options.Audience = "crmApi";
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new 
         TokenValidationParameters()
         {
            ValidateAudience = false
         };
   });
```

You can try out second option to verify if you setup api scopes properly.

Read more on my blog [here](https://nahidfa.com/posts/migrating-identityserver4-to-v4/)

Comment: i do have these

Comment: is it on DB? can u post snapshot of your DB records? @PeterKennan

Comment: posted db records

Comment: @PeterKennan added another option for u on the response

Comment: @PeterKennan If you are adding these on DB, we data on `ApiResources ` and also `ApiResourceScopes`

Comment: .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers()) i have removed this and now i am getting user is not authenticated when i try and login to identity server

Comment: added the records for you to view.

Comment: The records looks ok, if db setup is ok it should work. Just to make sure issue is cause of audience check in api, can u apply option 2 I posted? option to set ‘ ValidateAudience = false’ - also add back users

Comment: IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions does not contain a definition for.

Comment: if i add back users that will take test users, i only want users from the database

Comment: you need to replace ur code on api with what I sent you

Comment: why? i want to use identity server authentication not jwt

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 projects
1-IdentityServer
2- Movie.Client
Everything works fine when I set projects to HTTPs
But when I set projects in HTTP, even though the login operation code is done correctly, but the user does not login.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You can ask a new question if you need to.